# Can I set a window variable in the Vue bootstrap file (main.ts)?

Tags: typescript, vite

I am trying to do something like the following...

```
const bootstrap = async ()=>{
    const response = await axios.get("https://.../environment");
    const config = response.data;
    window.audience = config.audience;
    const app = createApp(App);
    app.mount("#app");
}
bootstrap().then(()=>{
    console.log("Bootstrap Completed")
});
```

But when I try this I get an error..

`TS2339: Property 'audience' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.`

How am I supposed to set a window variable here?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope not yet still looking